# A society including all human beings

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I want to refer to the society of all human beings. I can use the word "society," but I sense that a society is a term for a limited number of people. For example, by society we can refer to the people of a country or city. In this sense, we can use the word societies.

But I need the society to include all human beings. Is society an appropriate word for this case? or is there a better word?

Sample sentence: By studying human "society", we understand that ...

Comment: A society including all human beings is called "world". Why is "world" not appropriate in your context? What's the context?

Comment: "By studying world, ..." does not seem to convey my meaning. Looks like we are studying stones, trees, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use ***human [society](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/society)*** to refer to all human beings:

> - the body of human beings generally, associated or viewed as members of a community:
>
>   - *the evolution of human society.*

(Dictionary.com)

From [Man and Nature](https://books.google.it/books?id=AkLndz_6xtgC&pg=PA103&dq=%22human%20society%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIiqWa7_3QAhVDBcAKHdflDmQ4ChDoAQhEMAY#v=onepage&q=%22human%20society%22&f=false):

> - While nature ***contrasts with human society*** and the outer world contrasts to the individual, the outer world includes ***both nature and human society***. Thus, the relation between man and nature is actually that ***between human society and nature***, not between an individual and one's ...

You can consider also the expression 
 ***human [population](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/population)***:

> - the total of individuals occupying an area or making up a whole

(M-W)

From [Human Population Dynamics](https://books.google.it/books?id=X_M8_3c8dyQC&pg=PA17&dq=%22human%20population%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq_aXr7_3QAhWIKcAKHWheBmcQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=%22human%20population%22&f=false):

> - This chapter describes a formal demographic perspective on human population dynamics. It first attempts to summarise ***the way in which human population dynamics are treated in the more technical and theoretical demographic literature.*** The next section considers some demographic ...

Answer (score 5):

**Humankind** or **mankind**

> Humankind-human beings considered collectively (used as a neutral
>   alternative to ‘mankind’).
>
> Mankind - human beings considered collectively; the human race.